# Google Calendar php API not returning nextsynctoken

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am getting weird problem in google php calendar api. It is not returning nextsynctoken.

```
This is var_export of $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);

Google_Service_Calendar_Events::__set_state(array(
   'collection_key' => 'items',
   'accessRole' => 'owner',
   'defaultRemindersType' => 'Google_Service_Calendar_EventReminder',
   'defaultRemindersDataType' => 'array',
   'description' => NULL,
   'etag' => '"p32o8lfd2qbkt20g"',
   'itemsType' => 'Google_Service_Calendar_Event',
   'itemsDataType' => 'array',
   'kind' => 'calendar#events',
   'nextPageToken' => NULL,
   'nextSyncToken' => NULL,
   'summary' => 'Meetings',
   'timeZone' => '',
   'updated' => '2017-01-30T10:18:50.782Z',
   'internal_gapi_mappings' => 
  array (
  ),
   'modelData' => 
  array (
    'defaultReminders' => 
    array (
    ),
    'items' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
   'processed' => 
  array (
  ),
))
```

While in api explorer, it is sending nextsynctoken.
Github link:
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/1141

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show the full request you are making what do you have in $opParms  this might help https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync

Comment: thanks @DaImTo I am using these param $optParams = array(
                'maxResults' => 500,
                'orderBy' => 'startTime',
                'singleEvents' => TRUE,
                'timeMin' => date('c'),
            );

Answer (score 4):

Thanks guys I got answer. Her
https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/610